# Too much space below norm of vector

Tags: vector

I'm trying to find the right definition for the norm of a vector. I used this macro before :

```
\newcommand{\norme}[2][]{\ensuremath{\left\lVert #2 \right\rVert_{#1}}}
```

(optionnal argument is to specify some special norms).

But it sometimes give bad result. Just look at this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}

\newcommand{\norme}[2][]{\ensuremath{\left\lVert #2 \right\rVert_{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \norme[p]{u}^2, \norme[p]{\vv{u}}^2, \norme[p]{AB}^2, \norme[p]{\vv{AB}}^2.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Problem is, when there is an arrow above the vector (i.e. when there is a asymmetry between the height and the depth of the argument of norme), the result looks a bit ugly.

[image: norm, versio 1]

I found this new definition on a french forum :

```
\newcommand\norme[2][]{%
  \begingroup\setbox0 \hbox{\ensuremath{#2}}%
  \edef\drule{\vrule height\the\dimexpr\ht0+.25ex\relax
    depth\the\dimexpr\dp0+.25ex\relax width.6pt }% 
  \quitvmode
  \hbox{\drule\kern.16667em\drule\kern.16667em \box0
    \kern.16667em\drule\kern.16667em\drule}\endgroup_{#1} 
}
```

Problem now is that the vertical bars do not seem to behave like delimiters, so the square and the p on the right of the norm looks a bit too close :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}

\newcommand\norme[2][]{%
  \begingroup\setbox0 \hbox{\ensuremath{#2}}%
  \edef\drule{\vrule height\the\dimexpr\ht0+.25ex\relax
    depth\the\dimexpr\dp0+.25ex\relax width.6pt }% 
  \quitvmode
  \hbox{\drule\kern.16667em\drule\kern.16667em \box0
    \kern.16667em\drule\kern.16667em\drule}\endgroup_{#1} 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \norme[p]{u}^2, \norme[p]{\vv{u}}^2, \norme[p]{AB}^2, \norme[p]{\vv{AB}}^2.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: norm, version 2]

What could I add to recover the proper behavior of my delimiters ?

Thanks for any help.

[Edit] I think what I need is put a "\mathopen" and a "\mathclose" somewhere in my macro definition, but I don't know where...

Comment: BTW: you should never use automatic `\left...\right` for this very reason. IMO there is no need to scale the norm on `\vv{u}`, as you have already seen they often get too big.

Comment: For the `\newcommand{\norme}[2][]{\ensuremath{\left\lVert #2 \right\rVert_{#1}}}` I suggest to see `dynbrackets` package.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use `\adjustbox` to manually set the height and vertical offset.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\norme}[2][]{\ensuremath{\left\lVert #2 \right\rVert_{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \norme[p]{u}^2, 
    \norme[p]{\vv{u}}^2, 
    \norme[p]{AB}^2, 
    \norme[p]{\adjustbox{raise=-0.5ex, set height=2.0ex}{$\vv{AB}$}}^2.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Could be useful for one or two vectors, but I type documents with lots of those norms, so it's not very practical... But I'll remember the trick ;-)

Comment: You can define a macro to automate this.

Answer (score 4):

Using `commath` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}

\usepackage{commath}

\begin{document}
\[\enVert[0]{u}^{2}_{p}, \enVert[0]{\vv{u}}^{2}_{p}, \enVert[0]{AB}^{2}_{p}, \enVert[0]{\vv{AB}}^{2}_{p}  \]
\[\enVert[1]{u}^{2}_{p}, \enVert[1]{\vv{u}}^{2}_{p}, \enVert[1]{AB}^{2}_{p}, \enVert[1]{\vv{AB}}^{2}_{p}  \] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, now the norm symbol on the last example is clearly too short :-) Too bad, the other three are quite alright !

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS It is true. In fact I have edited my answer using the factor scale 1. :-)

Comment: +1, but I wonder where and how you find this (to me exotic) packages like `commath` :-)

Comment: @Zarko LOL :-) ahahahh. And yet I not remember of a new recent package for the brackets that I have not download :-)))))))))))))))))))).

Comment: @Sebastiano : problem is, the scale factor works like the initial setting : if you augment the height, you also augment the depth :-(

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS Yes it is true. But you use this package in other occasions. Don't worry.

Comment: The package indeed seems very interesting ;-) I found at least one or two constructions that I had hard time setting correctly !

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP` from math tools to define  `norme`. It defines a star version, which is equivalent to a pair of implicit `\left … \right` in front of the delimiters, or use an optional argument among `\big, \Big, \bigg, \Bigg`, which is equivalent to a pair of `\bigl … \bigr`, &c.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esvect}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\norme[1]{}\lVert\rVert{_p}{#1}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation*}
  \norme*{u}^2, \norme*{\vv{u}}^2, \norme*{AB}^2, \norme*{\vv{AB}}^2.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \norme*{u}^2, \norme*{\vv{u}}^2, \norme*{AB}^2, \norme[\big]{\vv{AB}}^2.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't really as flexible as the one the OP is using, in the version generated by DeclareP... the `p` is fixed. One cannot easily switch to `q`. That said, I'd used this one as well.

Comment: @daleif: Maybe  it might be done using  `xparse`, but I didn't have time to test. Anyway, I think most of the time, only a small set of indices it used, so it is as simple to define a `\pnorm`, a`\qnorm`, and so on.

Comment: I agree, it isn't really worth using an extra optional argument for